# Post Form data to different Domain in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have tried to post Form data from my mvc site to Other domain without page refresh[`Ajax.post`]. But the form data not saved in other domain.While I am posting same data to normal form post:`This data saved into Marketo site.
Can you suggest if there is any possible way to post the form data to cross domain without page refresh?

First Name:

Email Address:

Subscription

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to post Form data from my mvc site to Other domain without page refresh[Ajax.post]. but the form data not saved in other domain.

That is because of the [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (CORS) restriction

<s>and to circumvent the CORS one of the possible solution is to make a proxy on your server side and have that proxy talk to the other domain that i thin what you mean by *"while i am posting same data to normal form post[]. this data saved into Marketo site."*</s>

> Can you suggest if there is any possible way to post the form data to cross domain without page refresh?

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

[Cross-domain Ajax -- brief introduction]

[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp)